# Why is cargo project failed?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I start to make cargo project with rust and catch this warning with failure... What does it mean? In more young version I didn't meet with this strange phenomen.
Why does it happen?

```
D:\computer_science\rust>rustc --version
rustc 1.22.1 (05e2e1c41 2017-11-22)

D:\computer_science\rust>cargo --version
cargo 0.23.0 (61fa02415 2017-11-22)

D:\computer_science\rust>cargo new simple_test --bin
warning: compiling this new crate may not work due to invalid wor
ation

failed to parse manifest at `D:\computer_science\rust\Cargo.toml`
     Created binary (application) `simple_test` project
```

Cargo.toml contains:

```
[package]
name = "simple_test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["serg"]

[dependencies]
```

Comment: can you put this as text into your question and not as screenshot?

Comment: Add your `cargo --version` to your question, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid `Cargo.toml` in `D:\computer_science\rust`. Remove or fix that file and `cargo new test1 --bin` should work from within the rust directory.

Comment: I don't know, can you post the Cargo.toml of the rust directory? I could reproduce with an empty Cargo.toml in a directory `rust` and then doing `cargo new test1 --bin` and got the same error as you did

Comment: which file is this now? `rust\Cargo.toml` or `rust\test1\Cargo.toml`?

Comment: now you're mixing up directories. In your question you are in directory `rust` and it complains that the `Cargo.toml` there is broken. Please delete `Cargo.toml` in the rust directory